# Force download file with PHP giving empty file

Tags: php, file, download

The end goal is for the user to download a .csv file. Right now I'm just testing trying to download a simple text file: test.txt. The only thing in this file is the word "test".

Here is the HTML code for files_to_download.php

```
Test file: <a href='test.php?file=test.txt'>Test.txt</a>
```

Code for test.php:

```
if(!(empty($_GET["file"])))
{
    $file_name = $_GET["file"];
    $path = "path/to/file";
    $fullPath = $path . $file_name;

    if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
      ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');

    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Disposition: inline; attachment; filename=\"$file_name\"");
    header("Content-Type: text/plain");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    readfile($fullPath);
}
```

I've tried variations of the headers above, adding more and removing others. The above seem to be the most common recommended on this site.

I've also tried changing

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
```

to

```
header("Content-Type: text/csv");
```

and get same results: empty .txt or .csv file.

The files are not empty when I open them directly (file browser) from the server. I've checked the permissions of the files and they're both 644, so the entire world can at least read the files. The directory is 777.

Is there a configuration on the Apache server I need to specify that may not be or am I missing something above.

Thanks for looking!

Comment: You should check `$fullPath` and ensure that it is the path you'd like. In your example, `$fullPath` is `"path/to/filetest.txt"` not `"path/to/file/test.txt"`.

Comment: The code works as-is for me if you replace `readfile($fullPath);` with `echo 'foo'`, so I'm voting for the path problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In most cases the path is wrong

Comment: This happened to be the issue. I have the file generated/exported in one page and then can be downloaded on a different page. Trouble is, the path to this file and the name of it can change based on the date. So, I was passing the name and directory in to the session. Problem was I didn't include "session_start()" at the top of the script. Works like a charm now!

Answer (score 1):

Read the text file, then `echo` the text out after your header() calls.

Here's how I have my csv download set up:

```
//downloads an export of the user DB
$csv = User::exportUsers();

header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=userdb.csv');
header('Content-type: text/csv');

echo $csv;
```

Where `exportUsers()` creates the csv data. You can easily just replace $csv with the contents of your text file, then echo it out.

And as far as your text file, you can use `file_get_contents()` to get the contents of your file into a string. Then echo that string.

Comment: The benefit here is that you can `var_dump($csv)` to make sure it contains what you think it contains, before blaming the headers.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the content length of the file:

```
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
```

Also, please have this in mind: [file inclusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_File_Inclusion)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the path was correct. And the download-forcing was working on windows, but not mac.

I figured out after few tests that the header **Content-Length** was failing. I was using the function filesize on a full url, like :

```
$url_my_file = "http://my-website.com/folders/file.ext";
header('Content-Length: '.(filesize($url_my_file)));
```

I replace it by

```
$url_my_file = "http://my-website.com/folders/file.ext";    
$headers  = get_headers($url_my_file, 1);
header('Content-Length: '.($headers['Content-Length']));
```

And ... It's working now :)