# Embedding Executable (.exe) files into php

Tags: java, php, html, exe

Basically I want to embed the executable file of "Catacomb Snatch" [new Mojang game] into my html webpage. I've looked around but I can't seem to find much information on this.

If it would make it easier I could even us a mixture of php[instead of html] and an exe [instead of java]to actually get it to work on my page.

What is the simplest way to embed the jar or exe file into a html or php page?

Information much appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean "embed?"  You want to call java methods from a jar file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [.exe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.exe) file is a windows executable file. This means your website won't be able to run it, except if it is a windows server.

In case of a windows server, PHP will still not be able to run an `.exe` file. PHP can run shell commando's, as stated in the php manual with [shell_exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php), which can run the `.exe` file. This will only execute the file on the server tho. Embedding an `.exe` file is impossible, except if you mean to make it a download.

If you wish make the `.exe` a download, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25553538/12437108) on stack overflow describes perfectly how to do that.

<del>To run a jar file on your website, you can use a [java applet](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java-applet), which would the the simplest way.</del>

[Applet tags](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_applet.asp) are not supported in HTML5